# How to use ngFor to auto populate text boxes in form?

Tags: angular, typescript, mean-stack

I am a novice Angular programmer. I wish to auto populate text boxes in a form, say **10 text boxes (10 rows) using ngFor directive**.

In all the examples of ngFor, I find that a list is populated based on an array. But I don't intend to do so.
Rather, I wish such that using ngFor, writing only once, all rows containing text-boxes will get populated.

Moreover, I intend to use **ngModel directive** as well in order to store their values. How can I write that using ngFor?

Comment: The best way to learn programming is to do. Have a go yourself, you'll be amazed at how far a little trial and error goes. The official Angular Tour of Heroes tutorial is a good place to start

Comment: Did you try anything? Provide a plunker at least.

Comment: This is my favourite part *In all the examples of ngFor, ... But I don't intend to do so*. I am a novice, but examples do shit :)

Comment: @ChristopherMoore: Will go through the complete tutorial in detail. But for *ngFor, there also they have mentioned only for arrays. Not otherwise (like a normal for loop instead of forEach loop).

Comment: @Kinduser: You can get the plunkr from here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/KyCN4y?p=preview

Comment: @AkashHazra *ngFor only works for javascript iterable objects. You can't just loop n times

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as Christopher wisely mentioned, `*ngFor` accepts only iterable objects. Secondly, your plunker had a lot of bugs and errors, had to fix it.

Changed your `labels` object into array of little objects.

If you need more feedback, let me know.

https://plnkr.co/edit/8kfOwr8Piw2zmJLudwpB?p=preview

Comment: Oh I see. This works as expected. And the concept of *ngFor got clear as well. 

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you need more help?

Comment: Yes, please. When I am trying to assign an ngModel to the text-boxes, I am unable to do so. 
Where am I doing wrong?
https://plnkr.co/edit/KyCN4y?p=preview

Comment: I think you are misleading the concept of `ngModel`. You can't store the value of every input inside model. But you can make a reference to it in separate variables.